IBM MQ Connection failure : xcsGetpwuid got password entry with user name too long (more than 13 characters)
I developed a Golang app that is connected with IBM MQ. I was able to connect locally and test it. Every thing worked well until I changed my laptop. Now when I try to connect to the app locally I got the "xcsGetpwuid got password entry with user name too long (more than 13 characters)." failure.
I don't have control of the user name on my laptop. I cannot create a new user.
Other information:

I'm using the IBM MQ DevToolkit for MacOS
The MQ connection for the app does not need a user/password

Is there a way to bypass this?
Thanks.

Maybe https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/discussion/xcsgetpwuid-got-password-entry-with-user-name-too-long helps?

What is the version of MQ Client ?- run dspmqver
What is the Mac chip architecture ? - run arch or uname -m

Where is the Queue Manager that you are attempting to connect to, running?

@chughts arch is arm64. The MQ server is working fine. I'm able to do a telnet from my laptop. Also, we are running pods (EKS) that is communicating with the MQ. The app is ok... It's just on my local that it is not working

@eik I saw it. The response is unclear. I'm looking for something (like a configuration) that could override the username taken by IBM for connection.

What does dspmqver report?
